# How to sum three random numbers in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a simple input. The task is for the user to guess the sum of three random numbers

**I tried**

```
guessr1 = input("Guess a number:")
answer1= print(random.randrange(1, 5))

guessr2 = input("Guess a number:")
answer2 = print(random.randrange(1, 5))

guessr3 = input("Guess a number:")
answer3 = print(random.randrange(1, 5))

final_sum_guess = answer1 + asnwer2 + answer3
```

- I do not know the whole functions of python
- I only know: variables, input(), print(), count(), replace(), and, or, if, elif, not, in, isinstance, if else, concatenation , f"{var}"
- I'm looking for an answer inside the limits of my knowledge in python

Comment: Why does the user have inputs, if he just need to find the sum why does he need to give individual values ?

Comment: The input was just for clarification of the process that i used. 

But then, i could just use guessr2 = print(random.randrange(1, 5))?

If yes, how i sum the guesses, and print them?

Comment: This is very unclear what you're tryuing to do, Is it : pick 3 random numbers, sum them, then the user has to guess the sum ? Because if yes, that is 100% same as guessing one random number, just just the range os possibilities if 3 times bigger

Comment: Yes azro, it would be
1- guess the numbers
2- now you know the numbers you guessed
3- then , you sum the numbers that you guessed
####
and the range is from 1 to 5

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that the return of a print statement is None. That means that after this line `answer1= print(random.randrange(1, 5))` `type(answer1)` is of `NoneType`. You can not sum `NoneType`.

This could run.

```
import random

guessr1 = input("Guess a number:")
answer1= random.randrange(1, 5)
print(answer1)

guessr2 = input("Guess a number:")
answer2 = random.randrange(1, 5)
print(answer2)

guessr3 = input("Guess a number:")
answer3 = random.randrange(1, 5)
print(answer3)

final_sum_guess = answer1 + answer2 + answer3
print(final_sum_guess )
```

Comment: Good catch! +1. Additionally, in Python 3.8 onwards, one could use an assignment expression to assign and print in the same statement: `print(answer1:=random.randrange(1, 5))` will store the result of `random.randrange(1, 5)` in `answer1` as well as print that result.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information with us. I have a question. Is the `:` correct? It seems to be an unusual syntax?

Comment: Thank you mosc9575,  for the answer. Appreciate it.

But, the concatenation only applies to strings, and if we concatenate it would give us a string and not an integer. Am I right? or the print function, in this case, does not alter the type of information?

Comment: Do you want to print a string? Then you can cast each answer as a string with `str(answer1)+ '  '  + str(answer1)+ '  ' + str(answer2)+ '  ' +  str(answer2)` .

Comment: @mosc9575 Yes, the expression is `:=` aka 'Walrus operator'. [Examples here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#examples-from-the-python-standard-library).

Comment: @JonyHadary The result of `input` is always a string. So if you want to treat them as numbers (`int`s) then do `int(guessr1) + int(guessr2) + int(guessr3)` to add three numbers. Or `sum(map(int, (guessr1, guessr2, guessr3)))`. `final_answer` is supposed to be the sum of three int's so `answer1 + answer2 + answer3` is correct but the variable name should probably be `actual_sum`. And the sum of guessr1-3 could be stored as `guessed_sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use:

```
print(final_sum_guess)
```

or maybe like this:

```
print(f'Th answer is {final_sum_guess}')
```